# Comparing dynamic fields of objects using equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java, search, object, collections

To compare the different objects of the same class with their contents like jobTitleId, classificationId, deptId & classificationId was to be done and do some manipulations later using Set and Map. I was able to do that by simply overriding the equals and hashCode methods of Object class and was able to fetch the information (like in the following Map).

```
Map<LocationData, List<LocationData>>
```

The following is the class I used (its been shown to you so that it can be referred for my problem statement):

LocationData class

```
package com.astreait.bulkloader;

public class LocationData {     
    String locId, deptId, jobTitleId, classificationId;

    @Override   
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {         
        LocationData ld = (LocationData)obj;        
        return this.deptId.equals(ld.deptId) && this.jobTitleId.equals(ld.jobTitleId) && this.classificationId.equals(ld.classificationId) &&
this.locId.equals(ld.locId);    
    }

    @Override   
    public int hashCode() {         
        return deptId.hashCode() + jobTitleId.hashCode() + classificationId.hashCode() +locId.hashCode();   
    }
}
```

Problem:

I'm already known to which all fields of this object I need to make the comparison.
i.e I'm bound to use the variables named classificationId, deptId, jobTitleId & locId etc.

Need:
I need to customize this logic such that the fields Names (classificationId, deptId, jobTitleId & locId etc) can be pulled dynamically along with their values. So, as far as my understanding I made use of 2 classes (TableClass and ColWithData) such that the List of ColWithData is there in TableClass object.

I'm thinking what if I override the same two methods `equals() & hashCode();`
such that the same can be achieved.

```
TableClass class #1

class TableClass{
    List<ColWithData> cwdList;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean returnVal = false;
                // I need to have the logic to be defined such that 
                // all of the dynamic fields can be compared
        return returnVal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int returnVal = 0;
                // I need to have the logic to be defined such that 
                // all of the dynamic fields can be found for their individual hashCodes
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

ColWithData class #2

```
class ColWithData{ 

    String col; // here the jobTitleId, classificationId, deptId, locId or any other more fields info can come.
    String data; // The corresponding data or value for each jobTitleId, classificationId, deptId, locId or any other more fields.

}
```

Please let me know if I'm proceeding in the right direction or I should make some any other approach. If it is ok to use the current approach then what should be performed in the equals and hashCode methods?

Finally I need to make the map as: (Its not the concern how I will make, but can be considered as my desired result from this logic)

```
Map<TableClass, List<TableClass>> finalMap;
```

**EDIT** I have been down voted. So, I made some modifications for my requirements again. (Please help me out solving this)

Comment: It's very unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. Maybe lay out for us very clearly what the specific problem is that you're trying to solve, and your full thought process as to how you will solve it. Then perhaps we can point your code in the right direction. As it stands, all I see is a bunch of not-implementations of methods that don't seem to have much to do with your problem--whatever that is.

Comment: Can't you use a Map<String,String> instead of a list of "ColWithData"? It would be much more easier to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` if you could iterate over the map keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this class `ColWithData` is kind of ugly.  You should be using a `Map<String,String>` :

```
package mypack;

import java.util.*;

public class TableClass {
    /* HashMap containing your values:
       map.put("locId", [data]);
       ...
    */
    public Map<String,String> cwdMap;

    public Map<String,String> getCwdMap() {
        return cwdMap;
    }

    public void setCwdMap(Map<String,String> cwdMap) {
        this.cwdMap = cwdMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TableClass tClass = (TableClass) obj;

        for(String col: this.cwdMap.keyset()){
            if (! tClass.cwdMap.get(col).equals(this.cwdMap.get(col)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hCode = 0;
        for(String col: this.cwdMap.keyset()){
            hCode = hCode+cwdMap.get(col).hashCode();
        }

        return hCode;
    }
}
```

In this code I never check for `null` values but your probably should.

There is another thing that confuse me in your code:

why use getter/setter if your property (`cwdList`) is `public`?

Comment: Thanks Eric it solved the problem by simply using Map. To make the data fetching handy I made use of getter/setter. Yeah but I guess the getter/setter are mostly used for injecting the objects. Please let me know more about the getter/setter.

Comment: You use getter/setter to avoid accessing the property directly.  This is why, in most cases, the property field is set to `private` which forces the use of the getter/setter to access it outside the class. But this is just a choice you have to make yourself. I advise you to read about POJOs and getter/setter anywhere on the internet !

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution and its working for me.
Please let me know if there could be the simple or any other way out finding the solution for this problem.

The code snippet is:

```
package mypack;

import java.util.*;

public class TableClass {
    public List<ColWithData> cwdList;

    public List<ColWithData> getCwdList() {
        return cwdList;
    }

    public void setCwdList(List<ColWithData> cwdList) {
        this.cwdList = cwdList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        TableClass tClass = (TableClass) obj;

        boolean returnVal = true;



        for(ColWithData cwd: this.getCwdList()){
            for(ColWithData innerCwd: tClass.getCwdList()){
                if(cwd.getCol().equalsIgnoreCase(innerCwd.getCol())){
                    if(!cwd.getData().equalsIgnoreCase(innerCwd.getData()))
                        returnVal = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnVal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hCode = 0;
        for(ColWithData cwd: this.getCwdList()){
            hCode = hCode+cwd.getData().hashCode();
        }

        return hCode;
    }

}
```

And finally made a map as said:

```
Map<TableClass, List<TableClass>> map = new LinkedHashMap<TableClass, List<TableClass>>();
```

displaying the things as desired.